# regexp - match numbers with two decimals and thousand seperator

Tags: php, regex

http://www.tehplayground.com/#0qrTOzTh3

```
$inputs = array(
    '2', // no match
    '29.2', // no match
    '2.48',
    '8.06.16', // no match
    '-2.41',
    '-.54', // no match
    '4.492', // no match
    '4.194,32',
    '39,299.39',
    '329.382,39',
    '-188.392,49',
    '293.392,193', // no match
    '-.492.183,33', // no match
    '3.492.249,11',
    '29.439.834,13',
    '-392.492.492,43'
);

$number_pattern = '-?(?:[0-9]|[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{3}[\.,]?)?(?:[0-9]|[0-9]{2}|[0-9]{3})[\.,][0-9]{2}(?!\d)';

foreach($inputs as $input){
    preg_match_all('/'.$number_pattern.'/m', $input, $matches);
    print_r($matches);
}
```

Comment: You're a member for over 5 Years. You should know how to ask a question. Please include the desired behaviour, what you tried, code sample and a single question on what doesn't work with errors if available.

Comment: the example is the best way to describe it.. have added a link to tehplayground.com so you can see how it executes.. Could write a long story about what works and what doesn't.. but it still alot faster with the example.. reg exp is not that simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are looking for

```
$number_pattern = '-?(?<![\d.,])\d{1,3}(?:[,.]\d{3})*[.,]\d{2}(?![\d.])';
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/uFAIUH) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kT2zJ7/2).

The anchors are not used, there are lookarounds on both sides of the pattern instead.

**Pattern details**:

- `-?` - an optional hyphen
- `(?<![\d.,])` - there cannot be a digit, comma or dot befire the current location 
  -`\d{1,3}` -  1 to 3 digits
- `(?:[,.]\d{3})*` - zero or more sequences of a comma or dot followed with 3 digits
- `[.,]` - a comma or dot
- `\d{2}` - 2 digits that are
- `(?![\d.])` - not followed with a digit or dot.

Note in PHP, you do not need to specify the `/m` MULTILINE mode and use the `$` end of string anchor,

```
preg_match_all('/'.$number_pattern.'/', $input, $matches);
```

is enough to match the numbers you need in larger texts.

**If you need to match them as standalone strings,** use a simpler

```
^-?\d{1,3}(?:[,.]\d{3})*[.,]\d{2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/kT2zJ7/4).

Comment: it matches `8.06.16`

Comment: `-?(?<![\d.,])\d{1,3}(?:[,.]\d{3})*[.,]\d{2}(?![\d.])` does not match `8.06.16`. I also removed the `$` and `/m` from the PHP demo, since you do not need them to match these numbers in larger texts.